# Extent of a proj4 string

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, coordinates, proj4js, cartesian

I have a custom proj4 string in which my data is represented in Cartesian local coordinates. The example proj4 is below.

`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=44.155877943 +lon_0=141.655514872997 +k_0=1.000004976 +a=6378137.0 +b=6356752.314200002 +x_0=-47551.646999999 +y_0=17490.29 +towgs84=0.0,0.0,0.0 +units=m +no_defs`

I don’t know the extent of the CRS and I would like to calculate in my end from the proj4 string. Is this possible?

Comment: Seeing your proj4 string would help in helping you.

Comment: added the proj4 as requested

Comment: Not something which can be determined without further information.  The valid extent of a CRS is fluid and depends on your requirements - for example do you have a grid to ground scale distortion limit defined?  Alternatively the relevant authority may have defined the area of applicability and published this to EPSG.

Comment: But we have the scale factor in the proj4 projection with datum shift definitions. Is that not enough for grid to ground?

Comment: Why are you using a scale factor that is greater than 1 in a transverse mercator projection? This means that nowhere you'll get true scale.

Comment: Maybe scale is not as expected. But are these details enough or not is the question